# Display small size logo on small screens and bigger size on bigger screens - Correct approach

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know similar question has already been answered before. But I am not able to figure out which is the best approach. I find out there are two approaches:

1. Use `img` tag and fetch two images, one for small size and one for large size. On Large screen keep small sized logo hidden and on small size screen vice versa.
2. Use css background and in media queries give different urls of logo for different resolutions.

But which is a more standard approach to achieve this. And in terms of SEO, I think using `img` tag is better at least for showing your website's logo. But in terms of performance you always need to download one extra image, resulting in one more request.

Besides these two ways, is there any other way also possible that I am missing?

Comment: why not load an one image and resize it with a css styling? <img src="img.jpg" style="width:80%;"> or give it a class and with @media (max-width: 499px) for mobile change the width

Comment: For two reasons, my logo contains our tag line as well so for the sake of clarity I am trying to display a logo without tagline in small screens and also I have read it somewhere that browser scaling of images is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Using media queries**

Responsive design always means using `@media` queries to selectively target the device screen size and orientation through CSS.You get a smooth experience with media queries. Firefox, Safari (including Mobile), Chrome, and Opera are all supporting it. Internet Explorer 9 will be supporting it, but 8 and below do not. For those browsers which do not support use javascript techniques like [***this***](http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/).

**Update:**

If you care about server side components,use [adaptive images](http://adaptive-images.com/).Otherwise if you care about double-requests then [source shuffling](http://www.jordanm.co.uk/lab/sourceshuffling) works for you.

**Reference**: I recommend reading [***this***](http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/).

Comment: Uh...I was actually asking for which of these two approaches is best or a standard practice. Both approaches uses media queries behind the scenes.

Comment: @Abhi To know which responsive images solution should you use always depends on your scenario. Please go through reference article and find your preferred one since you have'nt recommended any criteria.

Comment: @Abhi See my updated answer. I recommend you to go through the reference article to get a better understanding. Hope it helps :)